# Polymer 2.0 Class heredy protected properties

Tags: javascript, class, polymer-2.x

I'm tying to create a classMixin in Polymer which provides custom methods and will be inherited by other elements.

Everything is working as expected, but I want to inherit some properties as well.

```
static get properties() {
    return {
        // Make this protected
        test: {
            value: 'test',
        }
    };
}
```

How would I make this `test` property protected, so it can be used by the inheriting class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an underscore when you declare it

```
    static get properties() {
    return {
        // Make this protected
        _test: {
            value: 'test',
        }
    };
}
```

[Refer here](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/properties#private-and-protected-properties)

Comment: Nice! Thanks. I've always thought an underscore would mark a private variable

Answer (score 0):

So there are no visibility modifiers like protected in JavaScript. To use these properties in different classes just create another mixin that declares the properties.

Comment: I've declared that exact code snippet above in my mixin. But I can't use them in my original class. `this.test` is `undefined`